# How to get page views using google analytics or reports

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-reporting-api

I am very confused with all the documentation. Some talk about reports and some talk about analytics and too much of information to go through.

I want to get page view or website visits using api call so I can show number of page views in my app.

I am using javascript and set up google analytics tracking like this:

```
// Start : Google Analytics Code
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){
      i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;
      i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments);
        },  i[r].l=1*new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
         m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async=1;
    a.src=g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m);
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-2', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
// Start : Google Analytics Code
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Is this not working? Are the page views not showing in Google analytics??

Comment: @W.Scott Its working but I want to get back the number of page views in to my app using api call

Comment: Ah, so your real question is: "How do I use JavaScript to get the number of page views from Google Analytics" Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018247/get-pageviews-from-google-analytics-api-in-javascript

Comment: If you say app, then is it native or hybrid mobile app? Or you just refer your website as web app ?

Comment: @Tushar Website with nodejs,html and javascript